# How to avoid insert repeated rules in nftables

Tags: nftables

In nftables I have this

```
table inet my_table {

    chain badips {

        ip saddr 185.165.190.17 counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop

    }
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;
        # Block badips
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump badips
}
```

The planning it to put a long list of IPs in `badips` chain. How can add only unique IPs? Is there nothing to avoid to add the same IP?

Now I run

```
nft add rule inet my_table badips "ip saddr <IP> counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop"
```

In nft rule, I see there is not `nft create rule` unlike chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't add one rule per ip. Just create a single rule, and use a [set](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Sets). E.g.:

```
table inet my_table {
        set badips_v4 {
                type ipv4_addr
        }

        set badips_v6 {
                type ipv6_addr
        }

        chain badips {
                type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
                counter ip saddr @badips_v4 drop
                counter ip6 saddr @badips_v6 drop
        }
}
```

With these rules in place, you block an ip by adding it to the appropriate set:

```
nft add element inet my_table badips_v4 { 185.165.190.17 }
```

If you run that statement multiple times, it doesn't add multiple items to the `set` -- a `set` is a collection of unique items, so if an item already exists in the `set`, adding it again is a no-op.